# Section header inside a Menu for a Picker not visible

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to have a `Section` header inside a `Menu` for a `Picker` in mit SwiftUI application, but it does not show up:

```
Menu {
    Section("Foo") {
        Text("Bar")
    }
    
    Section("Filter") {
        Picker(selection: $events.filter, label: Text("Filter options")) {
            Text("Upcoming events").tag(EventListRequest.Filter.upcoming)
            Text("Past events").tag(EventListRequest.Filter.past)
        }
    }
    
    Section("Order") {
        Button("Ascending") {}
        Button("Descending") {}
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get a section header above a Picker?

[image]

Comment: How do you show a menu with `Menu {}` without a label in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when the picker style is the default of `.inline` then the section header is always hidden.

Here are two possible workarounds.

**1. Use picker style `.menu`**

The section header is shown if you change the picker style to `.menu`. But then the picker is collapsed. So it's a compromise.

```swift
Section("Filter") {
    Picker(selection: $events.filter, label: Text("Filter options")) {
        Text("Upcoming events").tag(EventListRequest.Filter.upcoming)
        Text("Past events").tag(EventListRequest.Filter.past)
    }
    .pickerStyle(.menu)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

**2. Use regular buttons with a custom `LabelStyle`**

As another possible workaround, the individual picker items can simply be listed as regular buttons inside the `Section`. A custom `LabelStyle` can then be used to show a checkmark against the item that is selected.

This gives almost the same appearance as an inline `Picker`, except that the checkmark is on the right instead of on the left.

```swift
struct MyLabelStyle: LabelStyle {
    let isSelected: Bool
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        if isSelected {
            configuration.icon
        }
        configuration.title
    }
}
```

```swift
Section("Filter") {
    Button { events.filter = .upcoming } label: {
        Label("Upcoming events", systemImage: "checkmark")
            .labelStyle(MyLabelStyle(isSelected: events.filter == .upcoming))
    }
    Button { events.filter = .past } label: {
        Label("Past events", systemImage: "checkmark")
            .labelStyle(MyLabelStyle(isSelected: events.filter == .past))
    }
}
```

[image: CustomLabel]

Comment: Answer updated with a second possible workaround

Comment: This is helpful, however I just want to keep use of Picker but anyway just add a header label... but seems like this is not possible?

Comment: @KAMIKAZE The first variant still uses a `Picker` , but the list of items is collapsed, so it's a compromise. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to have the title show when the default picker style of `.inline` is used.

Comment: I just found that you can just add `Section("") { Text("Sort By")` this will add it.. but you can't change text size... but just color.