# Increase size of Picker / drop down when displaying symbols with large font

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, symbols, picker

I want to scale size of the Picker selection drop down consistently with the font size of the elements. I'm using code below to display a picker / drop down with list of symbols:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pickerSelection: String = "sun.min"
    let symbols = ["sun.max.fill", "sun.min.fill", "sun.min", "figure.walk"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Icon label", selection: $pickerSelection) {
                ForEach(symbols, id: \.self) { symbolString in
                    Text(Image(systemName: symbolString))
                }
            }
            .scaledToFit()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

### Preview

[image: sample list]

## Problem

I would like to increase size of the labels and make the picker labels, bigger, let's say I true to use `.font(.title)` to achieve that:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pickerSelection: String = "sun.min"
    let symbols = ["sun.max.fill", "sun.min.fill", "sun.min", "figure.walk"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Icon label", selection: $pickerSelection) {
                ForEach(symbols, id: \.self) { symbolString in
                    Text(Image(systemName: symbolString))
                        .font(.title)
                }
            }
            .scaledToFit()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This looks hideous:
[image: broken ui with label]

*How can I properly control the size of text/icon label within the Picker/drop-down element and expand it consistently with the size of the menu items?*

I'm open to alternative UI elements that would enable me to achieve the same outcome in a presentable manner - drop down list with symbols, where I can control size of the whole element and scale accordingly with the size of the symbol.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible.  If I remember correctly, the selected item of an `NSPopupMenu` object will expand automatically when opened in Cocoa.  Otherwise, the menu will automatically adjust to house the selected if not open, which doesn't seem to happen in SwiftUI.

Comment: @ElTomato No problem, thanks for your comments. Let's see if someone can offer a solution. I would be also open to use an alternative component if I can get similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try applying a `.scaleEffect` to the `Picker`.

- By default, the `Picker` fills the full width of the screen. To prevent this, apply `.fixedSize()` or set a `maxWidth`.
- The scale effect applies to the picker label and the menu icon too. However, it doesn't seem to apply to the items seen in the expanded menu (unfortunately).
- To keep the picker label at the regular size, supply an empty string to `Picker.init` and use a leading `Text` element instead. You might also like to add an `.accessibilityLabel` to the `Picker`, as substitute for the missing label.
- For the picker items, I found it worked best to use a `Label` with label style `.iconOnly`, instead of wrapping the images as `Text` items.
- Use padding to compensate for the scaling having an impact on layout, if necessary.

```swift
VStack {
    HStack {
        Text("Icon label")
        Picker("", selection: $pickerSelection) {
            ForEach(symbols, id: \.self) { symbolString in
                Label(symbolString, systemImage: symbolString)
                    .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
            }
        }
        .accessibilityLabel("Icon label")
        .fixedSize()
        .scaleEffect(1.5)
        .padding(.trailing, 14)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
}
.padding()
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

*EDIT* After a bit more experimentation, I found that you can get closer to a fully scaled result by using a `Menu` instead of a `Picker`:

- The menu is formed as a collection of `Button` items.
- The label for each `Button` is formed as an image wrapped as `Text`, as used in your original example. This gives the larger appearance for the expanded menu that was missing from the previous solution above.
- A checkmark can be integrated into the label to show the currently selected item.
- The menu button itself is styled using a custom `ButtonStyle`. This gives you a lot of control over its appearance.

I also tried the technique of showing the checkmark against the selected item by switching label style, as shown in part 2 of the answer to [Section header inside a Menu for a Picker not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77957870/20386264) (it was my answer). However, in this context, the checkmark is shown on the left, so this was causing the options to go out of alignment.

```swift
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            configuration.label
                .scaleEffect(1.5)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            Image(systemName: "chevron.up.chevron.down")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(3)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                        .fill(.blue)
                )
        }
        .padding(4)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                .fill(Color(NSColor.controlColor))
                .shadow(radius: 2)
        )
    }
}

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("Icon label")
        Menu {
            ForEach(symbols, id: \.self) { symbolString in
                Button {
                    pickerSelection = symbolString
                } label: {
                    Group {
                        if pickerSelection == symbolString {
                            Text(Image(systemName: symbolString)) +
                            Text("    ") +
                            Text(Image(systemName: "checkmark"))
                        } else {
                            Text(Image(systemName: symbolString))
                        }
                    }
                    .font(.title)
                }
            }
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: pickerSelection)
        }
        .accessibilityLabel("Icon label")
        .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
        .fixedSize()
    }
    .padding(.bottom, 150)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, this definitely looks much better than my initial concept. I see that after clicking the [expanded list of options follows default font](https://pasteboard.co/njmKQsydFnjC.png) do you know if there would be a way to adjust size of that list as well? So far, it's the best approach.

Comment: Pleased it helped, thanks for accepting the answer. Yes, the scaling doesn't seem to apply to the items in the expanded menu. Here, your original approach with font size for text labels works better. I'll keep trying some variations of `Label` and `.labelStyle` to see if there is any way to get the best of both worlds and will update the answer if successful.

Comment: Answer updated with another approach that uses a `Menu` instead of a `Picker`

Comment: Excellent contribution, thank you!